# SQL Server: 1 server multiple clients

Tags: sql-server, server, client

I'm writing a program for a small office (<5 client). All the computers are located at the office and I have a server too.

I want to install SQL Server on the server, and install my program on every client computer, and they will update data on the server.

Do I need to worry about conflicts? Do I need to write another program or service to run on the server to handle the clients request? Or is my program alone and the SQL Server service is enough?

What things I need to take into consideration in implementing this?

I'm new to this, so any additional help would be useful!

Thanks

Comment: "Do I need to worry about conflicts' - Depends! Will people be editing the same data at the same time?

Comment: SQL Server is a *server*, its designed to service multiple concurrent client connections over a network. Your program and an SQL Server installation are all you need to get connected.

Comment: There is a Table called "Orders" for instance, that multiple clients may be editing at the same time, yes.
To solve this I need a whole program to handle these issues? or is there a way to do it in my program itself ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Comment: This to broad a question for SO, maybe try the https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ site

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will generally handle this without problems. But from a functional point of view there may be things to consider, such as two people opening the same item, both making a change, and both saving their change at different points in time.

Without countermeasures, the last person to save 'wins'. If that is OK, then all is OK, but you should at least discuss it and document it.
If it is not OK then you might need e.g. a timestamp column, and then saving an item could be disallowed if the timestamp on the server was changed in between opening the item and saving the item.
Another approach is 'locking' or 'checking out' items, which has its own advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Wow thanks for the timestamp idea, it makes a lot of sense and I think will solve my problem!